# JS Extract numbers in parentheses from text file and filter out to be used in calculation

Tags: javascript, html

My text file has some numbers in parentheses that I would like to extract and use them in a function for some calculation. I have the code below to filter out the strings from the text file and output them... but I'd also like to use the numbers for calculations. like below is an example of I'd like to extract from text file.

passage (16333.614,-8500.850),(13000.638,-10465.827),(7775.276,-15735.827)

```
function readText(that){

        if(that.files && that.files[0]){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {  
                var output=e.target.result;
                var output2=e.target.result;
                var output3=e.target.result;
                var output4=e.target.result;        

                output=output.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /country/);
                output2=output2.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /\passage/).join("\n");
                output3=output3.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /\country side/).join("\n");   
                output4=output4.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /test/).join("\n");
                document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML= output + output2 + output3 + output4;
```

Comment: so you want the numbers `16333.614,-8500.850,13000.638,-10465.827, 7775.276,-15735.827` like in array or something ? and in that case can you please share  the line example from where you are getting these lines, it's not clear from your current question

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using regex, you might as well match the whole patterns and group the numbers to retrieve them.

For example to match the "passage" kind of line you presented, assuming they all have the same number of number pairs :

```
var input = "something something passage (16333.614,-8500.850),(13000.638,-10465.827),(7775.276,-15735.827) and then something again";
var result = input.match(/passage\s*\(([-\d.]+),\s*([-\d.]+)\),\s*\(([-\d.]+),\s*([-\d.]+)\),\s*\(([-\d.]+),\s*([-\d.]+)\)/);
console.log(result[0]); // the whole text
console.log(result[1]); // the "16333.614" string, can be cast to number
//[...]
console.log(result[6]); // the "-15735.827" string, can be cast to number
```

In that regex `[-\d.]+` represent a variable number (which is a non-empty sequence of `-`, `0..9` and `.` characters), which I'll call `<number>` in the following.
`\((<number>),\s*(<number>)\)` is a pair of numbers that are separated by a comma and optional spaces. Each of the two numbers are enclosed in grouping parenthesis. The outside literal parenthesis have to be escaped. I'll call it `<pair>` in the following.
`passage\s*<pair>,\s*<pair>,\s*<pair>` makes the whole regex : it matches text starting with passage which has three pairs separated by commas and optional spaces.

I hope this is enough to get you going !

Comment: it returns null... I forgot to mention... there are more text to the file other than the line passage above.